# Access Derived class properties from base class collection

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have created a derived class from a base class and have added the derived class objects to the base class collection.Later when i try to cast the collection objects to derived class,it is throwing error and i am not able to get my override methods and properties.How could i get around this.?

I am trying to override the stroke class in wpf inkcanvas.But the collection available is of base ink collection.So after serializing ans desalinizing,the new properties that i added is not accessible.Pls help

Comment: Casting the collection element should work. Example code would really help.

Comment: It would also help to say *what* error you got. I would guess InvalidCastException but it could be any number of others, depending on why it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `StrokeCollection` implements a custom `TypeConverter` which serializes the stroke data in an efficient binary format called [Ink Serialization Format](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/digformatspecs/InkSerializedFormat%28ISF%29Specification.pdf) (ISF) using the `StrokeCollection.Save()` method.  When your strokes are converted to ISF all the extra data is lost, so when they are reloaded they are instantiated as ordinary `Stroke` objects (not your subclass).  This is why you cannot cast them to your subclass.

Some of your options are:

- Subclass `StrokeCollection` and implement a new `TypeConverter` for your subclass
- Use a different serialization technique that ignores the `TypeConverter`
- Manually serialize your `StrokeCollection` (eg. by copying the `Strokes` into a `List<Stroke>` and serializing that)